# Getting a java;23 error; saying '{' is expected but brackets look fine to me

Tags: java

please help getting "java:23 error: '{' expected" to me the brackets look right, appreciate the help!
is there something else that I am missing? I've only just started getting into writing code and so far have loved it. I've done c# and visual basics as well as now taking Java.

```
//Pizza applet to assist customers when ordering pizza
//I had to make a pizza during this assignment :)

//Import packages
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PizzaShop extends JApplet
{
   //Declare variables
   private int intBold;
   private JCheckbox tomatoCB, grennPepperCB, blackOliveCB;
   private JCheckBox MushroomCB, extraCheeseCB, pepperoniCB, sausageCB;   
   private JRadioButton smallRB, mediumRB, largeRB;   
   private JRadioButton thinRB, halfRB, panPizzaRB;   
   private ButtonGroup sizeBG, typeBG;   
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private Jbutton processB;
   private JLabel orderL;
   private EventHandler eHandler;
}
   public class PizzaShop()
   {

   public void init()
   {
      //Set up layout
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.setLayout(null);

      eHandler = new EventHandler();

      //Establish checkboxes
      tomatoCB = new JCheckBox("Tomato");
      greenPepperCB = new JCheckBox("Green Pepper");
      blackOliveCB = new JCheckBox("Black Olive");
      mushroomCB = new JCheckBox("Mushroom");
      extraCheeseCB = new JCheckBox("Extra Cheese");
      pepperoniCB = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
      sausageCB = new JCheckBox("Sausage");

      //Set size and location
      tomatoCB.setSize(100, 25);
      greenPepperCB.setSize(100, 25);
      blackOliveCB.setSize(100, 25);
      mushroomCB.setSize(100, 25);
      extraCheeseCB.setSize(100, 25);
      pepperoniCB.setSize(100, 25);
      sausageCB.setSize(100, 25);

      tomatoCB.setLocation(50, 85);
      greenPepperCB.setLocation(50, 110);
      blackOliveCB.setLocation(50, 135);
      mushroomCB.setLocation(50, 160);
      extraCheeseCB.setLocation(50, 185);
      pepperoniCB.setLocation(50, 210);
      sausageCB.setLocation(50, 235);

      //Add CheckBox to layout
      c.add(tomatoCB);
      c.add(greenPepperCB);
      c.add(blackOliveCB);
      c.add(mushroomCB);
      c.add(extraCheeseCB);
      c.add(pepperoniCB);
      c.add(sausageCB);

      //Set pizza size radio buttons
      smallRB = newJRadioButton("Small $6.50");
      mediumRB = newJRadioButton("Medium $8.50");
      largeRB = newJRadioButton("Large: $10.00");

      //Set size and location of pizza buttons
      smallRB.setSize(100, 25);
      mediumRB.setSize(100, 25);
      largeRB.setSize(100, 25);
      smallRB.setLocation(225, 90);
      mediumRB.setLocation(225, 130);
      largeRB.setLocation(225, 170);

      //Set group for pizza size
      sizeBG = new ButtonGroup();
      sizeBG.add(smallRB);
      sizeBG.add(mediumRB);
      sizeBG.add(largeRB);
      c.add(smallRB);
      c.add(mediumRB);
      c.add(largeRB);

      //Set pizza type
      thinRB = new JRadioButton("Thin Crust");
      halfRB = newJRadioButton("Medium Crust");
      panPizzaRB = new JRadioButton("Pan");

      //Set pizza type size and location
      thinRB.setSize(100, 25);
      halfRB.setSize(100, 25);
      panRB.setSize(100, 25);
      thinRB.setLocation(370, 90);
      half.setLocation(370, 130);
      PanRB.setLocation(370, 170);

      //Set type of pizza to button group
      typeBG = new ButtonGroup();
      typeBG.add(thinRB);
      typeBG.add(halfRB);
      typeBG.add(panRB);
      c.add(thinRB);
      c.add(halfRB);
      c.add(panRB);

      //Add process button set size and location and activate event
      processB = new JButton("Process Order");
      processB.setSize(200, 30);
      processB.setLocation(210, 220);
      c.add(processB);
      processB.addActionListener(eHandler);

      //Add label for output and set size and location
      orderL = new JLabel("Your Order:");
      orderL.setSize (100, 30);
      orderL.setLocation(40, 270);
      c.add(orderL);

      textArea = new JTextArea();
      textArea.setVisible(true);
      textArea.setSize(450, 110);
      textArea.setLocation(40, 300);
      c.add(textArea);      
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paint(g);
      //Set text for welcome greeting
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", intBold, 24));
      g.drawString("Welcome to Home Style Pizza Shop", 30, 30);

      //Set text for each topping
      g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", intBold, 24));
      g.drawString("Each Topping: $1.50", 40, 80);
      g.drawRect(30, 60, 150, 210);

      //Set text for pizza size and type
      g.drawString("Pizza Size", 220, 80);
      g.drawRect(210, 60, 130, 150);
      g.drawString("Pizza Type", 370, 80);
      g.drawRect(360, 60, 130, 150);
   }
   private class EventHandler implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         //Declare variables
         double amountDue = 0.0;
         String str = " ";

         //See whats checked in pizza type
         if (e.getSource() == processB);
         {
            str = str + "Pizza Type:";

            if (thinRB.isSelected())
               str = str + "Thin Crust \n";
            else if (halfRB.isSelected())
               str = str + " Medium Crust \n";
            else if (panRB.isSelected())
               str = str + "Pan Crust \n";
         }     
         str = str + "Pizza Size: ";

         //See what's checked in pizza size
         if(smallRB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Small \n";
            amountDue = amountDue + 6.50;
         }
         else if (mediumRB.isSelected())
         { 
            str = str + "Medium \n";
            amountDue = amountDue + 8.50;
         }
         else if (largeRB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Large \n";
            amountDue = smountDue = 10.00;
         }
         str = str + "Toppings: ";
         //Check toppings add 1.50 each per checked box
         if (tomatoCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Tomato, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (greenPepperCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Green Pepper, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (blackOliveCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Black Olive, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (mushroomCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Mushroom, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (extraCheeseCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Extra Cheese, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (pepperoniCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Pepperoni, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         if (sausageCB.isSelected())
         {
            str = str + "Sausage, ";
            amountDue = amountDue + 1.50;
         }
         //Display order
         str = str + "\nAmount Due: $" = amountDue;
         textArea.setText(str);

      }


   }

   }
```

Comment: `public class PizzaShop() {` after the class definition. I suggest you download and use an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans which will help you learn the syntax. A good book wouldn't be a bad idea, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `}` after `private EventHandler eHandler;` will close the class definition, which is not what you are wanting.

Also `public class PizzaShop() {` would be wrong and not needed.  Maybe you are thinking of a constructor?

I suggest that you use a IDE like eclipse which allows you to click on menu items to create classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your closing brace on line 22 is *finishing* the class definition and the code after that seems to be trying to re-start it. Get rid of it. You should have:

```
private JLabel orderL;
private EventHandler eHandler;

public void init() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra closing brace before

```
public class PizzaShop()
```

And I presume the above line is meant to be a constructor, not another class declaration:

```
public PizzaShop() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same class defined twice in a file, in fact each class should probably be in another file (or it needs to be an inner class of some kind) -

```
public class PizzaShop extends JApplet
{
  //Declare variables
  private int intBold;
  private JCheckbox tomatoCB, grennPepperCB, blackOliveCB;
  private JCheckBox MushroomCB, extraCheeseCB, pepperoniCB, sausageCB;   
  private JRadioButton smallRB, mediumRB, largeRB;   
  private JRadioButton thinRB, halfRB, panPizzaRB;   
  private ButtonGroup sizeBG, typeBG;   
  private JTextArea textArea;
  private Jbutton processB;
  private JLabel orderL;
  private EventHandler eHandler;
} // <-- Here
public class PizzaShop() // <-- we just did this class.
```